# Dynamic Update SQL Tables - Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to do a dynamic update of SQL tables
for that I created 2 pages: dynmicQ.aspx.cs and updateUserQ.aspx.cs
I set that when you click on the update button in the output table of dynmicQ it will go to updateUserQ And will Preform an update
But the 'submit' remains Null so no action is taken.
I can't figure out where the problem was I did the same thing on another project and it worked fine

dynmicQ.aspx.cs:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                { // print table
                    BuildT += "<tr>";
                    BuildT += "<form method='post' action='updateUserQ.aspx' >";
                    BuildT += "<td><input type='submit'  name='submit' id='submit' value='update'/></td>";

                    BuildT += "<td><input type='button' onclick='window.location.href=\"removeUserQ.aspx?id=" + table.Rows[i]["Id"] + "\"' value='remove' /></td>";

                    if (table.Rows[i]["Admin"].ToString() == "1")
                        BuildT += "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='Admin' value='true' checked /></td>";
                    else
                        BuildT += "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='Admin' value='false' /></td>";

                    BuildT += "<td><input type='text' name='Password' value='" + table.Rows[i]["Password"] + "' /></td>";

                    BuildT += "<td><input type='text' name='Lname' value='" + table.Rows[i]["Lname"] + "' /></td>";
                    BuildT += "<td><input type='text' name='Fname' value='" + table.Rows[i]["Fname"] + "' /></td>";
                    BuildT += "<td>" + table.Rows[i]["Id"] + "</td>";
                    BuildT += "<input  type='hidden' name='Id' value='" + table.Rows[i]["Id"] + "' />";
                  
                 
                    BuildT += "</form>";
                    BuildT += "</tr>";
                }
                BuildT += "</table>";
            }

            st = BuildT;
```

updateUserQ.aspx.cs:

````
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "MzDb.mdf";
            if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
            {
                int idNum = int.Parse(Request.Form["Id"]);
                int isAdmin = 0;
                string Lname = Request.Form["Lname"];
                string Fname = Request.Form["Fname"];
                //string BdDate = Request.Form["BdDate"];
                //int Coins = Request.Form["Coins"];
                //string About = Request.Form["About"];
              
                if (Request.Form["Admin"] != null)
                {
                    isAdmin = 1;
                }
                string Password = Request.Form["Password"];
                string sql = "UPDATE Users SET Id = " + idNum + "";
                sql += ", Lname=N'" + Lname + "'";
                sql += ", Fname=N'" + Fname + "'";
              
                sql += ", Admin='" + isAdmin + "'";
                sql += ", Password='" + Password + "'";

                sql += " WHERE ID = " + idNum + "";
                AdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sql);
                Response.Redirect("dynamicQ.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Is it only `submit` that is `null`, or is it all input fields that is `null`?

Comment: the submit is null so it is not go to the rest

Comment: Yes, but that was not my question. Can you see if the other input values is also `null`.

Comment: the other input values is ok @FrankNielsen

Comment: Please use parameters otherwise you are at risk of SQL injection. And do not store plain-text passwords, using hashing instead